# SqlDataReader not throwing an exception

Tags: ado.net

I have method

```
public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(SqlCommand cmd, int level = 0)
{
    SqlConnection conn = cmd.Connection;
    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = SqlConnectionTimeOut;

    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime end = new DateTime();

    try
    {
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlex)
    {
        end = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan requestDuration = end - start;
        LoggerHelper.Info("SqlException - Execute reader duration before exception in milliseconds: " + requestDuration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
        LoggerHelper.Error("Execute reader ", sqlex ,cmd);

        if (sqlex.Number == 1205 && level <= 3) // will try to execute 3 times before throwing an Process deadlocked exception
        {
           LoggerHelper.Info(cmd.CommandText + " was a victim of deadlock. This was attempt " + (level + 1).ToString());

           dr = ExecuteReader(cmd, level++);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Execute reader ", sqlex);
        }

        // throw new Exception("Execute reader ", sqlex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        end = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan requestDuration = end - start;
        LoggerHelper.Info("Exception - Execute reader duration before exception in milliseconds: " + requestDuration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
        LoggerHelper.Error("Execute reader ", ex, cmd);

        throw new Exception("Execute reader ", ex);
    }

    return dr;
}
```

which is called from DAL

```
SqlDataReader reader = DataBridgeDb.ExecuteReader(TrisuraCommand);
datatable.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, tablenames);
```

While debugging a SQL deadlock exception is properly thrown in `ExecuteReader` method.

But when I deploy or change connection string to staging database, exception is thrown in `datatable.Load` method.

Does anyone know why? I think it comes to database properties difference or SQL Server difference?

Comment: What's the `Message` property of the thrown exception in datatable.Load?

Comment: Is this method part of the DAL?

Comment: It would be easier to see what could be going wrong if your kept your database objects local to where they are used. I always know there are potential problems when I see the connection state being checked. You should be in control of the state locally.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on this line in the `catch` block:

```
dr = ExecuteReader(cmd, level++);
```

The `++` operator doesn't increment `level` until *after* the function call, so it passes `0` again the second time. And the third. And so on. You need this:

```
dr = ExecuteReader(cmd, level++);
```

As shown in this sample .Net Fiddle program:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/NWTZtS

I'm not sure how that causes the issue. I'd expect a StackOverflowException, the deadlock to eventually resolve, or an SqlException with a number other than 1205. But this **is** a bug, and I strongly suspect somehow tit is allows the method to eventually return a `null` value for the SqlDataReader object. At that point, of course the `DataTable.Load()` method will complain.

Comment: actually i this was little older code. i do have proper implementation. Problem is that code works when i point to Dev database but it does not work when i poin to Staging. in later case cmd.ExecuteReader is not throwing deadlock exception but instead DataTable.Load. In this case reader is not null as one would expect

Comment: @D.Lukic `DataTable.Load()` cannot throw an SqlException of any kind; the sql has already completed. We need to see the exact exception message.